# Stored procedure help required

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am running this stored procedure and I need it to return a string value of

```
Success
```

or

```
Failed
```

But the following procedure is missing something, not sure what?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Log_Audit]
(
    @username varchar(254) = NULL,
    @password varchar(254) = NULL,
    @User_ID int = NULL,
    @Method varchar(10) = NULL,
    @Result varchar(10) = Failed
)
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   INSERT INTO dbo.[A_Logins]([Username], [Password], [User_ID], [Method], [Result])
   VALUES(@userName, @Password, @User_ID, @Method, @Result)

   SET NOCOUNT OFF;
   RETURN
```

It should return `@Result` as it will be having a `Success` or `Failed` message

Comment: ' ' around Failed in the ALTER Procedure statement

Comment: Side note for **SQL Server**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Comment: Furthermore: it's rather unclear as to *when* you want to return `Success` and when you want to return `Failed` - what's the criteria? Also: I would recommend to return numeric or `BIT` values - rather than strings - to indicate state - strings just are messy because of spelling (upper- / lower-case, different alphabets etc.)

Comment: if the @rESULT is inserted as `'Success'`, it should return Success else Failed for `'Failed'`

Comment: But why do you need to *return* a value that you're taking in as a parameter? Doesn't really make any sense.... the calling code *already* has that value - what's the point of returning it??

Comment: I want to return, the last @return value, because i will be passing from another query which sends the result value, so it is assumed if no value is send, it returns failed, else it should false

Comment: @Sammm did you try the solution i answered? This should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't return any value, can you try this at the place of where you wrote return?

```
       SELECT @Result As ReturnVal
```